# Interrupt arduino routine to run a slow delay based process

Tags: c++, arduino, delay, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I have an arduino that does mostly data collection and sends it to an ESP8266 over serial. Serial communication to the ESP is not quick as you may know and it depends on a lot of waiting. I have a button and I want to immediately stop any data collection or sending and have it open a door. The door opening takes about 30 seconds. What's the best way to do this?

Not the full code, but it goes something like the below.
Of course this doesn't work because you can't use WHILE or DELAY in an ISR, but I don't know how to restructure it.

```
attachInterrupt(4 , openadoor, FALLING);

void loop(){
gathersomedata();
senddatatoESP();
if(wait_for_esp_response(2000,"OK")) lightGreenLED();
else lightRedLED();
}  

byte wait_for_esp_response(int timeout, const char* term) {
unsigned long t = millis();
bool found = false;
int i = 0;
int len = strlen(term);
while (millis() < t + timeout) {
    if (Serial2.available()) {
        buffer[i++] = Serial2.read();
        if (i >= len) {
            if (strncmp(buffer + i - len, term, len) == 0) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
buffer[i] = 0;
}


void openadoor(){
while (doortimer + dooropentime >= millis() && digitalRead(openbutton)  == HIGH && digitalRead(closebutton)  == HIGH) {
    digitalWrite(DoorOpenRelay, LOW);
    }
digitalWrite(DoorOpenRelay, HIGH);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR - see Nick's Answer.  :-)

Without the complete code, I can only guess at a few things:

**1)** You shouldn't wait in an ISR.  Even calling `millis()` is discouraged, as it depends on the Timer0 ISR getting called, which will be prevented as long as you're in your `openadoor` ISR.

**2)** In general, the ISR should only do things that are very quick... think microseconds.  That's tens to hundreds of instructions, which can be just a few lines of code.  Even `digitalWrite` is almost too slow.  If there's more to do, you should just set a `volatile` flag that is watched in `loop`.  Then `loop` can do the time-consuming work.

**3)** Calculating elapsed time *must* be in this form:

```
if (millis() - startTime >= DESIRED_TIME)
```

where `startTime` is the same type as `millis()`, a `uint32_t`:

```
uint32_t startTime;
```

You set `startTime` whereever it's appropriate:

```
startTime = millis();
```

This avoids the rollover problem, when `millis()` rolls over from **2<sup>32</sup>-1**  to **0**.

**4)** It looks like you know how to "block" until a certain amount of time has elapsed: the `while` loop will keep your sketch at that point.  If you just change it to an `if` statement, the Arduino can continue on its way to handle other things.

Because `loop` happens so quickly, the `if` statement will check the time very frequently... unless you `delay` or block somewhere else, like `wait_for_esp_response`.  :-(  That while loop should change to an `if` statement as well.  The routine is more like `check_for_esp_response`.

**5)** You have to track the state of the door opening and closing process.  This is a [Finite-State machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) problem.  Nick has a good description [here](http://www.gammon.com.au/statemachine), too.  You can use the `enum` type to define the states that the door can be in: CLOSED, OPENING, OPENED and CLOSING.

When the OPEN button is pressed, you can look at the state and see if you should start opening it.  Then start a timer, turn on the relay and, most importantly, set the state to OPENING.  Next time through `loop`, you can test the state (a `switch` statement), and for the OPENING case, look at the time to see if it has been long enough.  If it has set the state to OPENED.  And so on.

If I incorporate all these things into your sketch, it should start to look like this:

```
volatile bool doorOpenPressed = false;
volatile bool doorClosePressed = false;

static const uint32_t DOOR_OPEN_TIME  = 30000UL; // ms
static const uint32_t DOOR_CLOSE_TIME = 30000UL; // ms
static const uint32_t DATA_SAMPLE_TIME = 60000UL; // ms

static uint32_t lastDataTime, sentTime, relayChanged;

static bool waitingForResponse = false;
static uint8_t responseLen = 0;

enum doorState_t { DOOR_CLOSED, DOOR_OPENING, DOOR_OPENED, DOOR_CLOSING };
doorState_t doorState = DOOR_CLOSED;

void setup()
{
  attachInterrupt(4 , openadoor, FALLING);
}

void loop()
{
  //  Is it time to take another sample?

  if (millis() - lastDataTime > DATA_SAMPLE_TIME) {
    lastDataTime = millis();
    gathersomedata();

    //  You may want to read all Serial2 input first, to make
    //  sure old data doesn't get mixed in with the new response.
    senddatatoESP();
    sentTime = millis();

    waitingForResponse = true;
    responseLen = 0; // ready for new response
  }

  //  If we're expecting a response, did we get it?

  if (waitingForResponse) {
    if (check_for_esp_response("OK")) {
      // Got it!
      lightGreenLED();
      waitingForResponse = false;

    } else if (millis() - sentTime > 2000UL) {
      // Too long!
      lightRedLED();
      waitingForResponse = false;

    } // else, still waiting
  }

  // Check and handle the door OPEN and CLOSE buttons,
  //   based on the current door state and time

  switch (doorState) {

    case DOOR_CLOSED:
      if (doorOpenPressed) {
        digitalWrite(DoorOpenRelay, LOW);
        relayChanged = millis();
        doorState = DOOR_OPENING;
      }
      break;

    case DOOR_OPENING:
      //  Has the door been opening long enough?
      if (millis() - relayChanged > DOOR_OPEN_TIME) {
        digitalWrite(DoorOpenRelay, HIGH);
        doorState = DOOR_OPENED;

      } else if (!doorOpenPressed && doorClosePressed) {
        // Oops, changed their mind and pressed the CLOSE button.

        // You may want to calculate a relayChanged time that
        //   is set back from millis() based on how long the
        //   door has been opening.  If it just started opening,
        //   you probably don't want to drive the relay for the
        //   full 30 seconds.
           ...
      }
      break;

    case DOOR_OPENED:
      if (doorClosePressed) {
        ...
      }
      break;

    case DOOR_CLOSING:
      if (millis() - relayChanged > DOOR_CLOSE_TIME) {
        ...
      }
      break;
  }
}

void openadoor()
{
  doorOpenPressed = true;
}

bool check_for_esp_response(const char* term)
{
  bool found = false;

  if (Serial2.available()) {
      // You should make sure you're not running off the end
      //   of "buffer" here!
      buffer[responseLen++] = Serial2.read();

      int len = strlen(term);
      if (responseLen >= len) {
          if (strncmp(buffer + responseLen - len, term, len) == 0) {
              found = true;
          }
      }
  }

  return found;
}
```

The key is that you don't block or delay anywhere.  `loop` gets called over and over, and it just checks a few variables.  Most of the time, there's nothing to do.  But sometimes, based on the state or the current time, it gathers some data, sends it, reads the response, and opens or closes the door.  These actions do not interfere with each other, because there are no blocking `while` loops, only quick checks with `if` statements.

Comment: Thanks immensely! This is exactly the restructuring advice I was looking for, plus lots of extra good stuff. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Your advice is really helpful. Is there a way I can buy you a coffee or two? paypal maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Open the door in the ISR and set a flag. Also store the time when you opened it. Both of those variables should be declared `volatile`.

Then in your main loop see if:

- The flag is set; and
- Time is up

If so, close the door (and clear the flag).

---

> May I assume that setting the variables as "volatile" will prevent the compiler optimizing them? If so, then would you mind explaining why you thought this necessary.

Variables modified inside an ISR may change when the compiler does not expect them to. Using `volatile` tells the compiler to reload such variables from RAM (and not cache them into a register) so it always gets the most up-to-date copy.

Just as an example, say you had a flag set inside an ISR. And in your main (non-ISR) code you had this:

```
flag = false;
while (!flag)
  { }  // wait for flag to be set
```

The compiler looks at that and thinks "well, flag will never change" and optimizes away the test for it changing. With `volatile` though, the compiler keeps the test, because it has to keep reloading `flag` from RAM.

Comment: May I assume that setting the variables as "volatile" will prevent the compiler optimizing them? If so, then would you mind explaining why you thought this necessary.